# perl script showing error: could not find file

Tags: java, perl

i'm trying to run the following perl script but it shows an error. the required files are i placed them in the same directory of the script file.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

@attackFileList=("_perParamDefaut_URLs.txt", "_perParam_URLs.txt", "_Cartesian_URLs.txt", "_Random_URLs.txt");
@legitFileList=("_Legit_URLs.txt");

$app=$ARGV[0];

print "Testing $app\n";
$startTime=time();
$attackCaught=$notCaught=$syntaxError=$other=$total=$error=$redirect=$success=0;
for $fileEnding (@attackFileList) {
    $fileName="$app$fileEnding";
    open(inputFile, "D:\\$app/$fileName") || die "Could not open $fileName\n";
    while ($line=<inputFile>) {
        chomp $line;
        @wget = split / /, $line;

        if ($wget[1] ne "--post-data") {
                        $wget[1] =~ s/"/\\"/g;
                $wget[1] =~ s/`/\\`/g;
                $wget[1] =~ s/_nosessions/_current/;
                $wget[1] =~ s/endeavor.cc.gt.atl.ga.us/localhost:8080/;
                $wget[1] =~ s/^\\"(.*)\\"$/"\1"/;
                $command=$wget[0]." -O - "."\"".$wget[1]."\"";
        } else {
                $wget[2] =~ s/"/\\"/g;
                $wget[2] =~ s/`/\\`/g;
                $wget[3] =~ s/_nosessions/_current/;
                $wget[3] =~ s/endeavor.cc.gt.atl.ga.us/localhost:8080/;
            $wget[2] =~ s/^\\"(.*)\\"$/"\1"/;
            $command=$wget[0]." -O - ".join(" ", $wget[1], $wget[2], $wget[3]);
        }

        $output=`$command 2>&1`;
        $retValue=$?>>8;
        if (($retValue == 0)||($output=~/302 Moved Temporarily/)) {
            if ($output=~/amnesia\.SQLIAException/) {
                    $attackCaught++;
                #print errorLog "PolicyViolationException:\n \t$wget[3]\n\t$wget[2]\n\t$command\n\n";
                } elsif ($output=~/amnesia\.UndetectedSQLIA/) {
                    $notCaught++;
                print errorLog "UndetectedSQLIA:\n \t$wget[3]\n\t$wget[2]\n\t$command\n\n";
                } elsif ($output=~/lexer\.SQLLexerException/) {
                    $syntaxError++;
                #print errorLog "SyntaxError:\n \t$wget[3]\n\t$wget[2]\n\t$command\n\n";
                } else {
                if ($output=~/302 Moved Temporarily/) {
                    $redirect++;
                }
                    $other++;
            }
            $success++;
        } else {
            $error++;
        }
        $total++;
        if (($total % 100) == 0) {print "$total, ";}
    }
    close(inputFile);
}
print "\n";
$endTime=time();

$elapsedTime=$endTime-$startTime;

print "**Testing Results: Attack**\n";
print "Total: $total\n";
print "\tValid URL requests: $success\n";
print "\t\tSQLIA detected: $attackCaught\n";
print "\t\tUndetected: $notCaught\n";
print "\t\tSyntax Errors: $syntaxError\n";
print "\t\tOther: $other\n";
print "\t\t\tRedirects: $redirect\n";
print "\tError URL requests: $error\n";
$omitted=$total-$error-$success;
print "\tOmitted: $omitted\n";
print "\nTime: $elapsedTime seconds\n";

open (outFile, ">>Effective.results") || die "Could not open Effective.results\n";
print outFile "$app-attk\t$total\t$success\t$attackCaught\t$notCaught\t$syntaxError\t$other\t$error\t$omitted\n";
close(outFile);

$startTime=time();
$attackCaught=$notCaught=$syntaxError=$other=$total=$error=$redirect=$success=0;
foreach $fileEnding (@legitFileList) {
    $fileName="$app$fileEnding";
    open(inputFile, "$app/$fileName") || die "Could not open $fileName\n";
    while ($line=<inputFile>) {
        chomp $line;
        @wget = split / /, $line;

        if ($wget[1] ne "--post-data") {
            $wget[1] =~ s/"/\\"/g;
                $wget[1] =~ s/`/\\`/g;
            $wget[1] =~ s/_nosessions/_current/;
            $wget[1] =~ s/endeavor.cc.gt.atl.ga.us/localhost:8080/;
            $wget[1] =~ s/^\\"(.*)\\"$/"\1"/;
                    $command=$wget[0]." -O - "."\"".$wget[1]."\"";
        } else {
            $wget[2] =~ s/"/\\"/g;
                        $wget[2] =~ s/`/\\`/g;
            $wget[3] =~ s/_nosessions/_current/;
            $wget[3] =~ s/endeavor.cc.gt.atl.ga.us/localhost:8080/;
            $wget[2] =~ s/^\\"(.*)\\"$/"\1"/;
            $command=$wget[0]." -O - ".join(" ", $wget[1], $wget[2], $wget[3]);
        }

        $output=`$command 2>&1`;
        $retValue=$?>>8;
        if (($retValue == 0)||($output=~/302 Moved Temporarily/)) {
            if ($output=~/amnesia\.SQLIAException/) {
                    $attackCaught++;
                print errorLog "SQLIAException:\n\t$wget[3]\n\t$wget[2]\n\t$command\n\n";
                } elsif ($output=~/amnesia\.UndetectedSQLIA/) {
                    $notCaught++;
                print errorLog "UndetectedSQLIA:\n \t$wget[3]\n\t$wget[2]\n\t$command\n\n";
                } elsif ($output=~/lexer\.SQLLexerException/) {
                    $syntaxError++;
                print errorLog "SyntaxError:\n \t$wget[3]\n\t$wget[2]\n\t$command\n\n";
                } else {
                if ($output=~/302 Moved Temporarily/) {
                    $redirect++;
                }
                    $other++;
            }
            $success++;
        } else {
            $error++;
        }

        $total++;
        if (($total % 100) == 0) {print "$total, ";}
    }
    close(inputFile);

}
print "\n";
$endTime=time();
close(errorLog);
$elapsedTime=$endTime-$startTime;

print "**Testing Results: Legit**\n";
print "Total: $total\n";
print "\tValid URL requests: $success\n";
print "\t\tSQLIA detected: $attackCaught\n";
print "\t\tUndetected: $notCaught\n";
print "\t\tSyntax Errors: $syntaxError\n";
print "\t\tOther: $other\n";
print "\t\t\tRedirects: $redirect\n";
print "\tError URL requests: $error\n";
$omitted=$total-$error-$success;
print "\tOmitted: $omitted\n";
print "\nTime: $elapsedTime seconds\n";

open (outFile, ">>Effective.results") || die "Could not open Effective.results\n";
print outFile "$app-legit\t$total\t$success\t$attackCaught\t$notCaught\t$syntaxError\t$other\t$error\t$omitted\n";
close(outFile);
```

call:
perl script.bat portal

result:
could not open file portal_perParamDefault_URLs.txt

Comment: Use `$!` to know the reason why open failed: `die "Could not open $fileName:$!";`

Comment: Yes. We'll all just drop everything and read dozens of lines of code for you. If you're going to ask for help here you should a) ensure that you're using `strict` and `warnings`, b) ask Perl for as much help as possible (i.e. using `$1` in your error message from `open`) and c) give us as small an extract from your program as we need to understand your problem.

Comment: You say that the files are in the same directory as the program. But what is the current working directory when you run the program?

Comment: @DaveCross: I think you mean `$!`

Answer (score 3):

Your coding is dreadful, but I suggest the answer to your question may be that you mean `_perParamDefault_URLs` where you have `_perParamDefaut_URLs`?

Before asking others to spare their time to help you, please be courteous enough to format your code properly so that it is readable, add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of your program and declare all of your variables using `my` close to their first point of use.

You should also use the lexical filehandles, the three-parameter form of `open`,  and add the `$!` variable to the contents of your die string. A boilerplate call to `open` should look like

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Unable to open '$filename': $!";
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows path can be handled with slash instead backslash, or better use `File::Spec` to handle it like:

```
my $full_path = File::Spec->catpath( "D", $app, $fileName )
open( inputFile, $full_path) or die $!;
```